# SQL Filter Orders by Customers Role

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables and i want display in my output list only orders who have customer role 0. 
this is my db :

#### table1

Table name : **customers** 
**id | role | name**  


1 | 0 | david
 
2 | 0 | Opera
3 | 1 | Jacob

#### table2

Table name : **orders** 
**id | customerid | title | price**  


1 | 1 | hello world | 100 
 
2 | 2 | hello world | 100
3 | 3 | hello world | 100

Comment: Which code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this with `INNER JOIN` and `WHERE` clause,

```
SELECT * FROM customers c 
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id=o.cusotomerid 
WHERE c.role=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a subquery like:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM customers B
              WHERE A.customerid=B.id
              AND B.role=0);
```